# How to mute/unmute MBP sound over HDMI

Tags: macos, audio, hdmi

I have a 2017 MacBookPro. When I connect my laptop to HDMI display, audio goes straight to HDMI. I can't control the volume. It is mildly annoying but I can understand there are some benefit in better sound quality.

What really bothers me is that I cannot mute/unmute the sound from my keyboard. Is there a way to let me control the HDMI audio from my laptop, at least mute/unmute?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article out on [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/04/use-hdmi-audio-output-mac-os-x/), worked for me

Comment: I read the article top to bottom. Maybe I am missing something but I don't see a solution to my problem. Unless you mean switching the audio from HDMI back to my internal speaker, which is not practical for me.

Comment: The solution above does allow you to switch it to a different audio out and then control the sound. If you want to be able to minipluate the volume being output via HDMI I am only aware of third party software that allows this. Here is an article about it: https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2017/03/how-to-enable-mac-volume-control-for-hdmi-or-displayport-audio/